# How can I add a resource to .qmlproject

Tags: qt-creator, qml, projects-and-solutions

I have created a new qmlproject using `New File or Project…` / `Applications` / `Qt Quick 2 UI with Controls`. I'd like to add resources (such as image files and fonts) to the project.

- When I rightclick on the project, the entry `Add Existing Files…` is greyed out.
- When I choose  `Add New…` / `Qt` / `Qt Resource file`, Qt Creator creates a new resource file, but then pops up an error message that the file could not be added to the project.
- When I drag an existing file from Finder to the project, Qt Creator open the file in a hex editor, but does not add it to the project.

I could not find any documentation on this, so this is why I would like to know: what is the standard way for adding a resource to a `.qmlproject`?

<sub>I'm using the version of Qt Creator bundled with Qt 5.2.0 beta 1</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.

The type of project wizard you chose is documented [here](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/quick-projects.html):

> Qt Quick UI (in the Other Project category) creates a Qt Quick UI project with a single QML file that contains the main view. You can review Qt Quick UI projects in a preview tool and you need not build them. **They do not contain any C++ code**.
>
> Qt Quick Controls UI is like Qt Quick UI, but using Qt Quick Controls.

The part in bold is key here, because `.qrc` files must be compiled into the application's executable, which can't happen when you don't have any C++ files to compile. Even if you had [external binary resources](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#external-binary-resources), there's no QML API to register them as far as I'm aware; only C++.

Newer versions of Creator seem to recommend against it:

> Creates a Qt Quick 2 UI project using Qt Quick Controls with a QML entry point. To use it, you need to have a QML runtime environment such as qmlscene set up. Consider using a Qt Quick Controls Application project instead.

I wouldn't recommend using the .qmlproject format. From memory, the last time I tried to deploy such a project to e.g. an Android device, it didn't work. You're better off using the "**Qt Quick Application**"/"**Qt Quick Controls Application**" project.